# load data from url ios for a webView to download and later use in a tableView

Tags: php, ios, uiwebview

I am trying to load simple data from a URL to use in a **TableView** on a different page.

So I need to figure out how to format it and pass it from my **WebView** to another **TableView** when done.

I can load the URL no problem, but I am wondering the best way to store and pass it?

The data I want is a tuple.
var myData = [("item1", "description1"),("item2","description2")]

I am seeing the data on the .php page within the **WebView**. When I click the link though, I'm not sure how to download the tuple for that link, store and pass it. And to then segue to the **TableView**.

More than anything, I guess I'm looking for some guidance on the next method to use to download and store it? Do I need to have the data be a json object, or can it just live in a .php variable?

This is my first time using the **WebView**. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post more code showing exactly what you're trying to do and where exactly you're stuck?

Comment: Thanks for responding John R. Fact is, I haven't written any code beyond loading the page. I guess, I was just looking for some suggestions. May not be the appropriate approach on this site? The question is, can I just pull down a variable that is a tuple from a .php page or do I have to use something like a .json object? I am going over the Apple documentation now. I may have gotten ahead of myself with the question. Thanks.